# Creating react app using create-react-app is taking long time and is not successful

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I know already there are some questions with similar issues with create-react-app but nothing is helpful. So please go through my issue once before duplicating it.

I am trying to create react application using create-react-app in Windows 10.

Below are the steps I followed in cmd.

1. Installed npm and node

```
C:\Users\jashe\Documents>npm -v
6.12.0

C:\Users\jashe\Documents>node -v
v12.13.0
```

2. Then used below npm commands to create the app

```
C:\Users\jashe\Documents>npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\jashe\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\jashe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
+ create-react-app@3.2.0
updated 1 package in 4.653s


C:\Users\jashe\Documents>create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\jashe\Documents\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> core-js@2.6.10 postinstall C:\Users\jashe\Documents\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node postinstall || echo "ignore"


> core-js@3.2.1 postinstall C:\Users\jashe\Documents\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

+ react@16.11.0
+ react-dom@16.11.0
+ react-scripts@3.2.0
added 1467 packages from 685 contributors and audited 904909 packages in 86.745s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

At this point it's taking long time like hours. But it was not successful even after that.

I tried using `npm cache clean --force` and `npx create-react-app my-app` as well. Even it's taking long time.

Even if I stop the process and tried to do `npm start` it's throwing below error. It didn't add all the dependencies I think

```
C:\Users\jashe\IdeaProjects\first-react-app>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jashe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-28T11_46_31_137Z-debug.log
```

Few months back I used create-react-app, it was working. Not sure why it's causing issue now. Any inputs will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Below are the logs:

```
C:\Users\jashe\my-app>type  C:\Users\jashe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-29T00_42_08_772Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:435:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:433:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\jashe\my-app
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
8 verbose node v12.13.0
9 verbose npm  v6.12.0
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Below is my package.json

```
 { "name": "my-app", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true, "dependencies": { "react": "16.11.0", "react-dom": "16.11.0", "react-scripts": "3.2.0" } }
```

Comment: What's your package.json look like? Also, what are the contents of the debug log file? You could also try npm run start instead of npm start. They should be the same thing but you never know, might as well try.

Comment: I tried npm run start. Still the same error.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the start script in your package.json. TRomesh's answer has the default create-react-app scripts. That should fix your problem.

Comment: even i had the same issue .. in my case i tried uninstalling the node js and  installed 32bit version ie x86 instead of 64 bit version .

Answer (score 1):

Delete you `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`and you don't have to install create-react-app globally. Instead you can use `npx create-react-app my-app` to create a react app. If this doesn't help can you please post the log of your `2019-10-28T11_46_31_137Z-debug.log` file?.

**Update**
your `package.json` file should have theses set of lines.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

But the code that you have shared doesn't include them. Try adding these to your `package.json`

Comment: Tried deleting package, node_modules and also uninstalled and reinstalled node.js. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

do it via powershell, its working that way but not from command prompt

Comment: Please provide more information for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem .

Yarn and npm was installed.
Seems some clash on node modules. So, uninstalled yarn and re-run `npx create-react-app <app_name>` works for me.